# awk to match keywords in two files

Tags: shell, awk

I am using the below command to match keyword from two files

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$0]=$0;next}{for(id in ids){if($0 ~ /\yid\y/){print}}}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Contents of `file1.txt`

```
work
run
```

file2.txt

```
I am running
I will run
```

desired output:

```
I will run
```

But I am not getting the desired output. What will be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ids[$0]=$0;next}{for(id in ids){if($0 ~ "\\y"id"\\y"){print}}}' file1.txt file2.txt
I will run
```

- `/\yid\y/` means matching whole word `id`, not contents of `id` variable
- `"\\y"id"\\y"` is concatenation of three strings - `"\\y"`, contents of `id` variable and `"\\y"`

  - `"\\y"` is needed to represent `\y` - see [gawk manual - Escape Sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html#Escape-Sequences)
- **note** that `FNR==NR{ids[$0];next}` will also work, no need to assign a value as only keys are needed

alternate solution using `grep`

```
$ grep -Ff file1.txt file2.txt
I am running
I will run
$ # -w option ensures to match only whole words
$ grep -wFf file1.txt file2.txt
I will run
```

use the `-F` option only if you need to match the strings literally

Comment: Please note `\y` is gawk-specific; it may not work in other awk implementations. +1 for the grep approach!

Answer (score 0):

For given inputs below awk also will work

```
awk 'FNR==NR{r=(r?r"|":"")$0;next}FNR==1{r="(^| )("r")( |$)"}$0~r' f1 f2
```

Test Results:

```
$ cat f1
work
run

$ cat f2
I am running
I will run

$ awk 'FNR==NR{r=(r?r"|":"")$0;next}FNR==1{r="(^| )("r")( |$)"}$0~r' f1 f2
I will run
```

Comment: Please note this approach demands words to be separated by space characters; it will not find `I run, therefore I am`.

Comment: @RuudHelderman You're right, it doesn't match, but OP hasn't mentioned anything in detail, probably with this `awk 'FNR==NR{r=(r?r"|":"")$0;next}FNR==1{r="(^|[^[:alnum:]])("r")([^[:alnum:]]|$)"}$0~r' f1 f2` it will give desired o/p for string you have given.